# problem with loading a tensorflow keras sequential model from scratch in a script after having saved it without any problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, input, keras, shapes

problem when trying to reload a saved tensorflow keras model from scratch in a new script with the .h5 file generated. It seems not to be able to rebuild the whole model based only on the .h5 saved file, it ask for an input shape at the first layer

```
mymodel = tf.keras.models.load_model("c:/temp/m_TESTBCCT.h5")
```

> WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr. W0511
>   08:14:29.234196  8096 hdf5_format.py:266] Sequential models without an
>   `input_shape` passed to the first layer cannot reload their optimizer
>   state. As a result, your model isstarting with a freshly initialized
>   optimizer. Traceback (most recent call last):   File ".\test0.py",
>   line 19, in 
>       mymodel.build()   File "C:\Users\xxxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py",
>   line 232, in build
>       raise ValueError('You must provide an `input_shape` argument.') ValueError: You must provide an `input_shape` argument.

Comment: If the model you used to train/create the saved model doesn't have an input_shape, it won't load correctly (per the error message). You'll have to re-train the model and ensure you have `input_shape` defined in the first layer of your model.

Comment: yes that was it ! thnks